# How can I check whether the quiz answer was correct?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a quiz for my computer science class and the basic concept is that you have 15 keywords and 15 definitions. All need to be randomly displayed and the correct answer has to appear. The user has to match the correct definition to the keyword twice and then that keyword and definition are not displayed again. When all have been answered twice the quiz is over.

I have stored both my keywords and my definitions in the same file so they don't get out of sync. The text file looks like so:

```
Keyword1,Definition1
Keyword2,Definition2
Keyword3,Definition3
...
```

Thanks to the help from others here on StackOverflow I have managed to get the randomizing and dictionary completed. For reference that looks like this:

```
Public Class form1

Const NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS As Integer = 3

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim kv As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Matt\Documents\keywords.txt")
        Dim parts() As String = line.Split(",")
        kv.Add(parts(0), parts(1))
    Next

    Dim r As New Random
    Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
      kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

    'questions will appear in random order
    For Each line As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In kvRandom
        Dim keyword As String = line.Key
        Dim correctDefinition As String = line.Value

        Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
        keywords.Add(keyword)
        keywords.AddRange(kv.Keys.Except({keyword}).
          OrderBy(Function() r.Next).Take(NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS - 1))

        Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
          keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

        LabelKeyword.Text = keyword
        RadioButtonDef1.Text = definitionsRandom(0)
        RadioButtonDef2.Text = definitionsRandom(1)
        RadioButtonDef3.Text = definitionsRandom(2)
    Next

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly. What I now need to do but I am finding difficult is on `button1_click` I need to check whether the answer was successful. In other words check that the definition checked is the right answer for the keyword. If so then display a Correct answer message otherwise display an error message and it randomizes again.

Another requirement is that each keyword should be matched to its definition twice, when that is completed it gets removed from the list and is not displayed again. In other words each question must be completed twice and when it is that question won't be displayed again. When all questions have been answered twice, the quiz ends. I do not know how to do this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if it is hard to understand what I am asking, I try to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that a dictionary structure contains only two parts; in this case, the question and the answer.  However, a third part is needed: the number of times answered.  This could be achieved by creating an `Answer` class, which contains the answer string and an Answered Boolean, e.g.:

```
Public Class Answer
    Public Answer as String
    Public Answered as Boolean
End Class
```

...then:

```
....
Private kv As Dictionary(Of String, Answer)
Private keyword As String 
Private correctDefinition As String 

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    kv = New Dictionary(Of String, Answer)
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Matt\Documents\keywords.txt")
        Dim parts() As String = line.Split(",")
        kv.Add(parts(0), New Answer with {.Answer = parts(1), .Answered = False}})
    Next
    RandomiseAnswers()
End Sub
```

`kv`, `keyword` and `correctDefinition` must be global to the form to allow interaction with code called by `button1_click`

When the question is answered the first time, set `.Answered` to `True`, and the second time, delete it from the list, in `button1_click`:

```
If (RadioButton1.Checked and RadioButton1.Text = correctDefinition) or (RadioButton2.Checked and RadioButton2.Text = correctDefinition) or (RadioButton3.Checked and RadioButton3.Text = correctDefinition) then
    If kv(keyword).Answered Then
        kv.Remove(keyword)
    Else
        kv(keyword).Answered = True
    End If
End If
RandomiseAnswers()
```

To prevent duplicate code in `Form1_load` and `button1_click`, create a subroutine:

```
Private Sub RandomiseAnswers()
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Answer)) =
      kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

    'questions will appear in random order
    For Each line As KeyValuePair(Of String, Answer) In kvRandom
        Dim keyword As String = line.Key
        Dim correctDefinition As String = line.Value.Answer

        Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
        keywords.Add(keyword)
        keywords.AddRange(kv.Keys.Except({keyword}).
          OrderBy(Function() r.Next).Take(NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS - 1))

        Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
          keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

        LabelKeyword.Text = keyword
        RadioButtonDef1.Text = definitionsRandom(0)
        RadioButtonDef2.Text = definitionsRandom(1)
        RadioButtonDef3.Text = definitionsRandom(2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks. If I may, could you show me how I would set `.Answered` to true the first time it is answered and the second time delete it? Also would this check if the answer was correct or would I need to add an If statement? Thanks again, you've really helped!

Comment: Matt, have a look at my edit with regard to `.Answered`.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting one error though which is: `kv(keyword).remove`. It says `remove` is not a member of `flashquiz.Answer`

Comment: Matt, sorry, it should be `kv.Remove(keyword)`.  I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Last quick thing. Do I need to do another if statement under `button1_click` to determine whether there are no questions left (all answered twice) and when there aren't go to a different form and how can I display a msgbox when they got the answer right and an error message box when the got it wrong showing them the right answer???

Comment: Also just realised that the form needs refreshing (to randomize again) after each question. How can I do that with this code? Thanks. These two are the last things. You have been a great help and it is truly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: From he looks of it, just run your code in `Form1_Load` `Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
      kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList
` to `Next` again - better to split it out into another subroutine.

Comment: I tried doing this `form1_load(Me, New System.EventArgs)` under `button1_click` however the Answers seem to not record how many times the user has answered the question so it might be resetting it. Is there any other way you suggest I can try?

Comment: Of course just running form1_load will reset things, that's why I said to re-run the section of code *after* the `kv = New Dictionary...` `For Each Line...` ... `Next` block, since that is what is resetting things. It is also why I suggested putting the subsequent section a separate procedure and calling it from form1_load and button1_click, to prevent redundant code.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I may seem a pain, I'm still learning visual basic so without examples a lot of things are alien to me.

Comment: Oh I see thanks, I don't know whether this is me entering it wrong but I get two errors: The first being: `Error 1 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, flashquiz.Answer))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String))'. C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\flashquiz\flashquiz\Form1.vb 55 11 flashquiz
` which is the following line: `kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList` and on this line `keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to allow for the `Answer` class.  Have a look now.

Comment: Thank you it works however it doesn't seem to remove the keywords and definitions when they are answered twice.